# How to add play/pause toggle for multiple onclick images with different audio src

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple images with onclick function to play different audio sources for each separate image. However, I also want a toggle or play/pause function that if you click on the same image again the audio pauses.

I have tried to incorporate .pause() and the toggle function, but I just don't get it work properly. Do you guys have any idea and suggestion how to use the pause and/or toggle function in this case?

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Falconfdfd/26n00ypp/1/)

```js
var aAudio = new Audio('a.mp3');
var bAudio = new Audio('b.mp3');
var cAudio = new Audio('c.mp3');

function myAudioFunction(letter) {
  if (letter == 'a') {
    aAudio.play();
  } else if (letter == 'b') {
    bAudio.play();
  } else if (letter == 'c') {
    cAudio.play();
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="myAudioFunction('a')" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Facebook" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://d2fi4ri5dhpqd1.cloudfront.net/public/resources/social-networks-icon-sets/circle-dark-gray/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="32" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;max-width: 32px !important">
</a>

<a onclick="myAudioFunction('b')" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Vkontakte" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://d2fi4ri5dhpqd1.cloudfront.net/public/resources/social-networks-icon-sets/circle-dark-gray/vkontakte@2x.png" alt="Vkontakte" title="Vkontakte" width="32" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;max-width: 32px !important"
  />
</a>

<a onclick="myAudioFunction('c')" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Vkontakte" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://d2fi4ri5dhpqd1.cloudfront.net/public/resources/social-networks-icon-sets/circle-dark-gray/vkontakte@2x.png" alt="Vkontakte" title="Vkontakte" width="32" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;max-width: 32px !important"
  />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `paused` property combined with the `currentTime` property to tell if an audio element needs to be paused or played when the button is pressed.

```
function myAudioFunction(letter) {
  var players = {
    a: aAudio,
    b: bAudio,
    c: cAudio
  };

  var player = players[letter];

  if (player.currentTime == 0 || player.paused) {
    player.play();
  } else {
    player.pause();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the audio is playing by checking its `paused` property. You also have to check if the audio was never started, you can do that using the `currentTime` property.

Here is an example:

```js
var aAudio = new Audio('a.mp3');
var bAudio = new Audio('b.mp3');
var cAudio = new Audio('c.mp3');

function myAudioFunction(letter) {
  toggleAudio(window[letter+"Audio"]);
}

function toggleAudio(audioElm){
   if(!audioElm.currentTime || audioElm.paused){
       audioElm.play();
   }else{
       audioElm.pause();
   }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="myAudioFunction('a')" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Facebook" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://d2fi4ri5dhpqd1.cloudfront.net/public/resources/social-networks-icon-sets/circle-dark-gray/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="32" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;max-width: 32px !important">
</a>

<a onclick="myAudioFunction('b')" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Vkontakte" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://d2fi4ri5dhpqd1.cloudfront.net/public/resources/social-networks-icon-sets/circle-dark-gray/vkontakte@2x.png" alt="Vkontakte" title="Vkontakte" width="32" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;max-width: 32px !important"
  />
</a>

<a onclick="myAudioFunction('c')" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Vkontakte" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://d2fi4ri5dhpqd1.cloudfront.net/public/resources/social-networks-icon-sets/circle-dark-gray/vkontakte@2x.png" alt="Vkontakte" title="Vkontakte" width="32" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;max-width: 32px !important"
  />
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this one as well and works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do that! Use the `paused` property

```js
var audiolinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");

//loop over all links | audiolinks is a nodelist without forEach - use Array's forEach
Array.prototype.forEach.call(audiolinks, function(element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    myAudioFunction(index);
  })
});

var aAudio = new Audio('a.mp3');
var bAudio = new Audio('b.mp3');
var cAudio = new Audio('c.mp3');
var audioPlaying = "|"; //use | to avoid selecting Audio element

function myAudioFunction(index) {
  res = String.fromCharCode(97 + index);
  //select char (a, b, etc.) and use bracket to combine it with audio.
  if (window[audioPlaying + "Audio"]) {
    if (!window[audioPlaying + "Audio"].paused && res == audioPlaying) {
      console.log("pause", audioPlaying);
      window[audioPlaying + "Audio"].pause();
    } else if (!window[audioPlaying + "Audio"].paused && res != audioPlaying) {
      console.log("stop", audioPlaying);
      window[audioPlaying + "Audio"].pause();

      window[audioPlaying + "Audio"].currentTime = 0;
    } else {
      console.log("play", audioPlaying);
      window[audioPlaying + "Audio"].play();
    }

  }

  //if res isn't audioPlaying, start the audio
  if (res != audioPlaying) {
    console.log("play", res);
    window[res + "Audio"].play();
    audioPlaying = res;
  }
}
```

```html
<a style="cursor:pointer;" title="Facebook" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://d2fi4ri5dhpqd1.cloudfront.net/public/resources/social-networks-icon-sets/circle-dark-gray/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="32" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;max-width: 32px !important">
</a>

<a style="cursor:pointer;" title="Vkontakte" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://d2fi4ri5dhpqd1.cloudfront.net/public/resources/social-networks-icon-sets/circle-dark-gray/vkontakte@2x.png" alt="Vkontakte" title="Vkontakte" width="32" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;max-width: 32px !important"
  />
</a>

<a style="cursor:pointer;" title="Vkontakte" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://d2fi4ri5dhpqd1.cloudfront.net/public/resources/social-networks-icon-sets/circle-dark-gray/vkontakte@2x.png" alt="Vkontakte" title="Vkontakte" width="32" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;clear: both;display: block !important;border: none;height: auto;float: none;max-width: 32px !important"
  />
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I try this code it seems to be that it only plays audio a for the first two images and audio c for the last image. Nonetheless, thank you